# Python Using IF inside FOR loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, dictionary

This question might be very silly but i am trying to use the dictionary to iterate and return the result. I know how to iterate over dictionary but i want to check if the entered key exists in the dictionary and i want the program to print if the value is present or not.

```
class companyx:

    def __init__(self,empid):

        self.empid=empid

    def employees(self):

        employees={1:'Jane',2:'David',3:'Chris',4:'Roger'}

        entered=self.empid

        for emp in employees :
            if emp == entered:
                print ('Hi '+employees[emp] +' you are an employee of companyx.com')
        print('You dont belong here')

emp=companyx(2)

emp.employees()
```

When i pass a parameter which is not in the dictionary, i want the function to print "You dont belong here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `in` keyword to quickly perform dictionary lookups:

```
if entered in employees:
    # the key is in the dict
else:
    # the key could not be found
```

Answer (score 9):

The easiest (and most idiomatic) way to check if a key is in a dictionary is:

```
if entered in employees:
```

The above replaces the `for/if` part of your code. Notice that there's no need to explicitly traverse the dictionary, the `in` operator takes care of checking membership. Short and sweet :) The complete code would look like this:

```
def employees(self):
    employees = {1:'Jane', 2:'David', 3:'Chris', 4:'Roger'}
    if self.empid in employees:
        print('Hi ' + employees[self.empid] + ' you are an employee of companyx.com')
    else:
        print("You don't belong here")
```

Comment: +1 this way you dont need to write the loop part (since its doing it anyways behind the scenes )

Comment: yea you can michael: `x = {'pie':'thon'} ; assert('pie' in x )`... hehe u knew what i meant :)

Comment: @TehTris: There is no loop behind the scenes. Also, `{'pie','thon'}` is a set.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if entered in employees.keys():
    ....
else:
    ....
```

Comment: No need for `keys()`: `if entered in employees`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate through the dictionary to do that. You can write:

```
def employees(self):

    employees={1:'Jane',2:'David',3:'Chris',4:'Roger'}
    employee = employees.get(self.empid)

    if employee:
        print ('Hi ' + employee + ' you are an employee of companyx.com')
    else:
        print ('You dont belong here')
```

Answer (score 2):

The most pythonic way to do this is to just try the lookup, and handle failure if it happens:

```
try:
    print('Hi '+employees[entered] +' you are an employee of companyx.com')
except KeyError:
    print('You dont belong here')
```

---

There's no reason for the `for` loop; the whole point of dictionaries is that you can look things up in one step, `d[key]`, instead of having to loop over the keys and check whether each one `== key`.

You could use `in` to check whether the key exists, and then look it up. But that's a little silly—you're looking up the key to see whether you can look up the key. Why not just look up the key?

You can do this by using the `get` method, which returns `None` (or you can pass a different default value) if the key is missing:

```
name = employees.get(entered)
if name:
    print('Hi '+name +' you are an employee of companyx.com')
else:
    print('You dont belong here')
```

But it's [Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission](http://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-eafp). Besides being slightly more concise, using `try` and `except` makes it clear that finding the name is the normal case that should be true, and not finding it is the exceptional case.

Comment: +1 Using `try/except` is indeed _the_ Pythonic way to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

No need for a for loop - you just need:

```
if entered in employees:
    print 'blah'
else:
    print 'You do not belong here'
```